# How to run a python spaCy script from c#?

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, .net-core, spacy

I have an example python script from [spacy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/training/train_intent_parser.py#L107), and I'm trying to find a way to run this script from c#. I've checked a couple of examples using simple scripts, but it's all confusing. Can anyone help me regarding this, please?

Comment: To help you, you should provide piece of code or what you tried. Even so you can read this article. It seems very easy with IronPython. 
https://medium.com/better-programming/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5